# PHP > How to type-cast each array element to string (recursively)...?

Tags: php

For instance, how to convert the following array:

```
$array1 = array("value1" => "20", "value2" => 40, array("value3" => 60));
```

To:

```
$array1 = array("value1" => "20", "value2" => "40", array("value3" => "60"));
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
array_walk_recursive($array, function (&$value) { $value = (string)$value; });
```

Comment: Note: Requires 5.3 for lamba function.

Answer (score 0):

You can write recursive function eg.:

```
function strArr($inp){
    $res=array();
    foreach($inp as $k=>$v){
        if(is_array($v)) $res[$k]=strArr($v);
        else $res[$k]=strval($v);
    }
    return $res;
}
$array1 = array("value1" => "20", "value2" => 40, array("value3" => 60));

$array2 = strArr($array1);
```

Answer (score -1):

Converting every element to a string without support for lambda functions:

```
array_walk_recursive($array, 'strval');
```

Comment: Converting every element to a string without support for lambda functions: `array_walk_recursive($array, create_function('&$value', '$value = (string)$value;'));` Simply `strval` as callback won't work.