# how can json_encode() not auto convert string to int

Tags: php, arrays, json

So i have this array,

```
Array 
(
    [0] => Array ( 
         [task] => Sleeping 
         [duration] => 2 
    )
    [1] => Array ( 
         [task] => Eating 
         [duration] => 1
    ) 
)
```

when i json_encode() it, it returns

```
 [{"task":"Sleeping","duration":2},{"task":"Eating","duration":1}]
```

i need it to be

```
 [{"task":"Sleeping","duration":"2"},{"task":"Eating","duration":"1"}]
```

is there any way how?

Comment: `[duration] => 2` -> `[duration] => "2"` ?!

Comment: Is the value in the array a string before you call json_encode?

Comment: A string it not a number in JSON or in PHP.. supply the intended value.

Answer (score 1):

The dump shows that the  variable inside the array is an int in the first place so cast it to a string before pushing it inside the array

Answer (score 1):

[json_encode](http://php.net/json_encode) outputs the values as per their [type](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.php), in your case they are integers. In order to have all values wrapped in quotes you need to [cast](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php#language.types.typecasting) each value as a **string**:

```
<?php
$data = array(0 => array('task' => 'Sleeping', 'duration' => 2), 1 => array('task' => 'Eating', 'duration' => 1));
array_walk_recursive($data, function (&$value) { $value = (string)$value; });

header('content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8');
echo json_encode($data);
```

Recursive string casting courtesy of [deceze](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9227881/128161)

Output:

`[{"task":"Sleeping","duration":"2"},{"task":"Eating","duration":"1"}]`

Pretty Print Output:

```
[
    {
        "task": "Sleeping",
        "duration": "2"
    },
    {
        "task": "Eating",
        "duration": "1"
    }
]
```